# SQL UNIQUE constraint on multiple columns - Is it the composite of them must be unique or at least one of them?

Tags: sql

I'm a SQL newbie here and I'm playing around with the `UNIQUE` constraint when creating a table. I'm obviously not understanding something fundamental here so bear with me.

Let's say I want to enforce that a User must have a unique username and a unique email. In other words, I don't want to have two users that have the same username nor two users that have the same email.

I have a `User` table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE User 
(
    id int,
    username nvarchar(20),
    email nvarchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE(username, email)
);
```

With the `UNIQUE` constraint defined above, it appears that the following inserts will succeed:

```
INSERT INTO User (id, username, email)
VALUES
    (1, 'aaron', 'aaron-email'),
    (2, 'aaron', 'aaron-email-2'),
    (3, 'bob', 'bob-email'),
    (4, 'bob', 'aaron-email');
```

It enforces that the composite of username and email must be unique in for the constraint to kick in. However, this obviously does not make sense as now we have multiple users with the same username and multiple users with the same email.

How do we enforce that both username and email columns must be unique?

Comment: FYI the behaviour might be different on different SQL server implementations, if your columns can be nullable. In some implementations your columns are currently nullable, because this is the default. You might want to check this. For example, if your column is nullable in MariaDB, then Maria essentially ignores that column if it is part of a unique constraint. (Which is weird and makes no sense, but that's how it's implemented.)

Comment: To make them not nullable, add `not null` after `id`, `username` and `email`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A syntax `UNIQUE(username, email)` assumes that a combination of the columns must be unique.

You can add multiple separate UNIQUE constraints to enforce unique conditions for each of the columns. The syntax that you use allows for multiple statements:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    id int,
    username nvarchar(20),
    email nvarchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE(username),
    UNIQUE(email)
);

INSERT INTO User (id, username, email)
VALUES
    (1, 'aaron', 'aaron-email'),
    (2, 'aaron', 'aaron-email-2'),
    (3, 'bob', 'bob-email'),
    (4, 'bob', 'aaron-email')
;

Duplicate entry 'aaron' for key 'User.username'
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/07o7fr-C

P.S. The same result can be also achieved with another (and more simple) syntax, by adding `UNIQUE` qualifiers to the columns themselves, for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    id int,
    username nvarchar(20) UNIQUE,
    email nvarchar(20) UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```